# C - Storing MD5 in a Sqlite Database

Tags: c, sqlite

**Q: How can I bind and retrieve an MD5 Hash from an Sqlite Database in C?**

I'm (somewhat) aware of the cryptographic [vulnerabilities of MD5](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38801/how-exactly-is-md5-vulnerable-to-collission-attacks) so have no intention of using this for anything other than a simple means to check file integrity.

I've observed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069744/difference-between-binary16-and-char32-when-storing-md5-in-database) that in a typical MySQL database the hash can be stored as either a `Binary(16)` or `Char(32)` type. Should I choose to use `Binary(16)` I would need to ensure that I store it as binary data, and not encoded in hexadecimal otherwise I risk loosing half of my MD5.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665623/is-there-a-direct-equivalent-in-sqlite-to-mysqls-binary) I've observed that whilst there is no `Binary(16)` or `Char(32)` type in Sqlite; there does in fact appear to be a Sqlite equivalent to `Binary(16)` however this may be through use of a binary blob `(b blob)`?

What I am uncertain of is how I would achieve this with the [Sqlite3 C API](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html). There does not appear to be a `sqlite3_bind_binaryblob` function that I can employ for this data type to send to my database. Likewise there is no apparent `sqlite3_column_binaryblob` which I can retrieve this data (I'm being intentionally simplistic here to illustrate what I'm looking for). I have a feeling I should just store the hash as a `blob`, am I right?

But if there is a `(b blob)` I can use, the addition complication is that I have no idea how to convert my data from hexidecimal to binary and back again as suggested in the [aformentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069744/difference-between-binary16-and-char32-when-storing-md5-in-database) (albeit python and not c) related question. If there is a much simpler way to achieve (such as just using a blob) how and (possibly) why I should do so would be a welcome suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a string (this wastes space) or better use a blob. Sqlite3 uses [manifest typing](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), the type specified in the `CREATE TABLE` statement is merely a suggestion.

Converting the MD5 sum from hexadecimal to binary is pretty straightforward, you can use the following snippet of code (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
static int hexchar(char c)
{
    const char *lookup = "0123456789abcdef";

    return (int)(strchr(lookup, tolower(c)) - lookup);
}

#define MD5LEN 128
extern void
md5tobin(unsigned char out[restrict MD5LEN/8], const char in[restrict MD5LEN/4])
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < MD5LEN/8; i++)
        out[i] = hexchar(in[2*i]) << 4 | hexchar(in[2*i+1]);
}
```

The function you use to bind a blob is called `sqlite3_bind_blob()`, to bind a string use `sqlite3_bind_text()`.

Comment: Wow that's going to take some unpicking I think. Based on my limited grasp of this function the `unsigned char out[]` is my md5sum and the `const char in[]` is my binary data populated by the function? So I would bind the `const char in[]` to either `blob` or could I use `char`? I'm not seeing a return so does this not render the `extern void` return moot?

Comment: @Chortle Yeah, for `in` you should pass a pointer to an MD5 hash as text. It should be a string of at least 32 characters. `out` should point to a buffer with at least 16 bytes space. The function is a bit weirdly written, it's possibly to wide a less complex implementation of the functionality. If you use this function to generate a binary hash, you should store the binary hash as a `BLOB` in the database. Alternatively, store the textual hash as `TEXT` in the database.